# EWS can't get all unreaded mail which is got error while reading

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have windows service that working every 10 second. It's working fine generally but sometimes im getting these errors;

at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
at OutlookService.ItemLoad(EmailMessage message, List`1& attachmentList) in \OutlookService.cs:line 69; The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
25.09.2019 15:03:53: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices:at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)

**My problem is if that mail got error while reading it cannot be read again. Its stay unread mail but i cannot get it.**

My Code;

```
    private static ExchangeService Service2013
    {
        get
        {
            if (_service2013 == null)
            {
                var uname = "mail";
                var pwd = "pass";

                _service2013 = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                _service2013.Credentials = new WebCredentials(uname, pwd);
                _service2013.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            }
            return _service2013;
        }
    }

 ExchangeService service = OutlookService.Service;

        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
        try
        {
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
            ItemView view = new ItemView(100);         
            do
            {
                findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
                if (findResults.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
                    {
                        item.Load(); 
                        var emailMessage = item as EmailMessage;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailMessage.Subject))
                        {
                            if (!emailMessage.Subject.ToLower().Contains("automatic reply") && !emailMessage.Subject.ToLower().Contains("otomatik yanıt"))
                            {
                                ReadMail(item as EmailMessage);
                                GC.SuppressFinalize(item);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                emailMessage.IsRead = true;
                                emailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ReadMail(item as EmailMessage);
                            GC.SuppressFinalize(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset.GetValueOrDefault(0);
                GC.SuppressFinalize(findResults);
            } while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(view);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Operate Error {0}.", ex.Message));
            Logger.WriteLog(ex);
        }
```

Comment: remove all the  GC.SuppressFinalize(view);

Comment: is the subject check meant to be and &&  -> NOT "automatic reply" &&  NOT "otomatik yanıt", should this not be an OR

Comment: and the read logic should be in that block?? instead of the else

Comment: @Seabizkit i dont think its about GC. if subject is not empty and afk mode deactived, it going to read it. Its should be && with operand

Comment: how sure are you that GC.SuppressFinalize has nothing to do with it(i was just stating if you read up on GC generally (99.9%) if you are calling it its a really bad idea.). perhaps make ExchangeService lifespan the duration of the each cycle unless you have something which says its a gd idea to have an indefinite static to ExchangeService.